# Is there an elegant way to check multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have multiple dropdown menus namely part_no,part_category,make and model. I am trying to display the quantity of vehicle parts in my inventory.

Given that as I become more specific by supplying more values to the dropdown menu, the less type of part has to be displayed. (Something like a filtering)

A good example that I am trying to mimick are the dropdown menus found in this website: http://www.sgcarmart.com/used_cars/listing.php?MMO=Mini&RPG=20&MOD=Austin

Is there a better way of doing the checking(through all possible combinations) rather than doing this:

```
         //Values from my dropdown menus
           var carmake= $('#car_make').val();
           var carmodel= $('#car_model').val();
           var partname= $('#part_name').val();
           var partcategory= $('#part_category').val(); 

           if(carmake==data['carmake'])
           {
           //do something
           }
           else if (carmake==data['carmake'] && partname==data['partname'])
           {
            //do something           
           }
           else if (carmodel==data['carmodel'] && partname==data['partname'])
           {
            //do something           
           }
           else if (carmodel==data['carmodel'] && partname==data['partname'] &&partcategory==data['partcategory'])
           {
            //do something           
           } else if (carmodel==data['carmodel'] && partname==data['partname'] &&partcategory==data['partcategory' &&partname==data['partname'])
           {
            //do something           
           }
           .
           .
           .
           .
           .
```

Comment: The first `else if` will never be executed. It's only executed if `carmake == data['carmake']` is false. But if that's false, then so is `carmake == data['carmake'] && anything`.

Comment: Nested `if` is your friend!

Comment: @Barmar yeah which is exactly what I wanted. If the combination has matched. It should immediately quit checking the conditions for the various else if statements

Comment: @user3659911 The point Barmar is saying that all the `else if`'s will always be false when the first `if` is false. Then when the first `if` is true the `else if`'s are not executed either. They don't do anything.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek Oh I think I get what you mean.Sry for not being explicitly clear in my post.

Comment: @Barmar  I did not write out all the else if statements. I added '...' which means it will definitely fall into one of the else if statement.

Comment: I know it will fall into some of them. I was just pointing out that some of them are impossible to reach, because of the relationship between the logic. If you're going to mix specific and general conditions, you need to either nest them or test the more specific ones first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your test values in an object whose property names are the same as in `data`. Then loop over all the properties to see if they're all the same:

```
var search = {
    carmake: $("#car_make").val(),
    carmodel: $("#car_model").val(),
    partname: $("#part_name").val(),
    partcategory: $("#part_category").val()
};

var match = true;
$.each(search, function(prop, value) {
    if (value !== "" && value != data[prop]) { // only compare if the dropdown was selected
        match = false;
        return false; // break out of the loop
    }
});

if (match) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: @ user3659911 Your attempted edit was wrong. There's no need to return true from the iteration function; `$.each()` keeps looping unless the function explicitly returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have added your codes in my source codes. When the combination is false, the match will be set to false. The match has to be set back to true when the combination is found. In order for  the if(match) statement to be executed.

Comment: `match` is initialized to `true` before the loop. It will only be set to `false` if `data` fails to match.

Comment: But you also have to take into account when the data succeeded in matching.

Comment: If it succeeds, `match` will still be true, since nothing sets it to `false`.

Comment: Sry I just reviewed it. Yup, the match will be reset to true when the $('selector').on('change',function() {( }); detects any changes in the dropdown menu.